# Pairwise independence of $\sigma$-algebras indicates mutual independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Let $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_N$ be mutually independent $\sigma$-algebras: For any distinct indices $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n \in \left\{1, 2, \dots, N \right\}$ and for any events $S_{i_1} \in F_{i_1}$,  $S_{i_2} \in F_{i_2}, \dots,  S_{i_n} \in F_{i_n}$ it holds that
$$ \mathrm{Pr} (\bigcap_{k = 1}^n S_{i_k}) = \prod_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Pr}(S_{i_k}). $$

Then it trivially follows that the $\sigma$-algebras are pairwise independent.

But does the converse hold? If $F_1, F_2, \dots, F_N$ are pairwise independent $\sigma$-algebras, are they also mutually independent? I guess yes, but what would be an easy way to see it?

Comment: What happens when you try to apply this to a simple example of three pairwise-independent random variables not being mutually independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ denote some probability space and let $A$,$B$ and $C$ be events that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.

Each of these events generates a $\sigma$-algebra. For instance for event $A$ we find $\sigma\left(\{A\}\right)=\{\varnothing,A,A^c,\Omega\}$.

It is not difficult to prove that here we deal with $3$ $\sigma$-algebras that are pairwise independent but not mutually independent.